# Two bootstrap modals side by side with responsiveness

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to open two bootstrap modal popups side by side using columns in bootstrap including responsive. I mean, in medium screen and large screen, modals should be side by side and in small and extra small screens one on top and another on the bottom. with 100% within their columns.

```
<div class="modal col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 pull-left" id="modal-one" data-backdrop=false data-keyboard="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                    &times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" style="color: black;">Test Header1
                    </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="modal col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 pull-right" id="modal-two" data-backdrop=false data-keyboard="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                    &times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" style="color: black;">Test Header2
                    </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script>
    $('#modal-one').modal();
    $('#modal-two').modal();
</script>
```

This is opening two modals but they are overlapping.

Here is my [JS-fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/phanindranath/roy2wd17/)

Comment: The Bootstrap documentation specifically says it doesn't support two modals open at the same time. Read the first callout box: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Rick. It is mentioned like, we need custom code, which does not mean Its impossible with Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
.modal {
position:relative;
}
```

Try it with a media query something like:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .modal {
        position: relative;
    }
}
```

Comment: [updated js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/technoGeek/roy2wd17/5/).
Thanks, TheEarlyMan, it has worked. But I messed up with some more difficult scenario. Can you check my js fiddler updated link it has updated? I want to open two model pop-ups at once from a button in the main modal popup. The problem is bootstrap columns are not working on the .modal div – techno geek 16 mins ago

Comment: [Here's a fork to the jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p1uwtbxk/) - Just place the .modal inside your `col-lg-6`